# Detect running process (and start if not run) under windows

Tags: php

Here is a code I use to check if process is running under windows, in this case calc.exe

I'm trying to start calc.exe if this one not figure out in task list.

If calc.exe is not started, is opened when run php script, but **page remain in a loop until i close calc.exe**.

Where do I wrong?

Help is appreciated.

```
// START SHOW TASKLIST
// Get Tasklist
exec("tasklist 2>NUL", $task_list);

//print_r($task_list);
echo '<pre>'; print_r($task_list); echo '</pre>';
// END SHOW TASKLIST


// Service running
$kill_pattern = '~(calc)\.exe~i';

// Create array
$task_list = array();

exec("tasklist 2>NUL", $task_list);

foreach ($task_list AS $task_line) {
  if (preg_match($kill_pattern, $task_line, $out)) {
    echo "=> Detected: ".$out[1]."\n   !\n";
    $is_running = '1';  
    break; 
  }
}

if ($is_running == '1') {
  echo 'Nothing to do';
  exit; 
} else {
  // open calc.exe
  exec("calc.exe");
  exit;
}
```

Comment: So what is your question?

Comment: have you read this part? >>> page remain in a loop until i close calc.exe.
Where do I wrong?

Comment: Hm. _Maybe_ you want "the page" (whatever that is)  to remain or maybe you _don't_ want it too? We don't know if you keep things that vague.

Comment: PHP is _typically_ executed inside a web server environment. In such situation it makes zero sense to have it open another process that is meant to work in an interactive manner ("...I close..."). So what is your situation, don't you thing you should specify that in the question? We cannot guess it...

Comment: Yes, i'm like to remain in same page.

Comment: Sorry, I fail to make more sense of that comment than before. What "page"? What does "like" mean here?

Comment: The [docs of exec](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php) clearly state: *If a program is started with this function, in order for it to continue running in the background, the output of the program must be redirected to a file or another output stream. Failing to do so will cause PHP to hang until the execution of the program ends.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use this code to avoid script hang up

Change

```
exec(calc.exe);
```

With

```
pclose(popen('start /B cmd /C "calc.exe >NUL 2>NUL"', 'r'));
```

Comment: Works like a charm. Thanks HID